# How to return document sources as images instead of text in RetrievalQA of langchain?

Tags: python, streamlit, langchain, large-language-model, py-langchain

I am building a document assistant that helps the user chat with documents. I've been successful in building one. I've used langchain, chromadb, qunatized llama2 and streamlit. While `RetrievalQA` of langchain has the option to set `return_source_documents` to either True or False; however, the source documents do not look visually appealing especially when document has tabular information. I want to show the source as an image in the streamlit app alongwith the document name.

```
if "QA" not in st.session_state:
    prompt, memory = get_prompt_template(promptTemplate_type='llama', history=False)

    QA = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
        llm=LLM,
        chain_type="stuff",
        retriever=RETRIEVER,
        return_source_documents=True,
        chain_type_kwargs={"prompt": prompt, "memory": memory},
    )
    st.session_state["QA"] = QA

prompt = st.text_input("Input your prompt here")

if prompt:
    response = st.session_state["QA"](prompt)
    answer, docs = response["result"], response["source_documents"]
    st.write(answer)

    with st.expander("Document Similarity Search"):
        search = st.session_state.DB.similarity_search_with_score(prompt)
        for i, doc in enumerate(search):
            st.write(f"Source Document # {i+1} : {doc[0].metadata['source'].split('/')[-1]}")
            st.write(doc[0].page_content)
            st.write("--------------------------------")
```